# Remove Old Version of Python Package on Install

Tags: python, django, python-module

I'm creating a Django package that contains some core functionality I will use across multiple web apps.

Now, this is the first time I'm creating a Django/Python package. I have read up on existing documentation and tutorials.

My problem is that, every time I make a change to the package and recreate the package, and reinstall it using the "python setup.py install" method, the new package is in fact installed, but the previous version remains.

So, for example, right now I have the latest 3 versions of the package installed in my machine.

How do I make it so an installation of the package removes all previous installations of the same package?

Thank you

Comment: How exactly are previous versions of your app persisting? Where/how are they installed? Whenever I run a `distutils` install, it always overwrites the last install location.

Comment: Well, on the setup output on the console it does seem the old version is removed, as there is a line referencing to that, but when I visit the site-packages folder it still contains the files for the older distributions.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. What happens if you `rm -r` that directory, then run an `install` command again?

Comment: Well, if I remove it "by hand" and install the package again, naturally the new package is installed. But I would rather avoid manually removing the old version everytime I change and reinstall my package.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known problem.

The reporter of [Issue 5342](http://bugs.python.org/issue5342) has the same issue with old files persisting in the install directory.

Per [Issue 4673](http://bugs.python.org/issue4673), `distutils2` now has an `uninstall` command that you could use to clean your directory on an install. Perhaps you could override the `install` command such that it first tries to uninstall an old package first?

---

Otherwise, it seems the solution is:

> to hack some old file detection into each package, or tell users 'delete
>   the old install first'.  Neither of which is really nice.